# Is there a way to clone a directory in an S3 bucket to another path within the same bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I've searched and read quite a bit but can't find an answer to this question so I assume it's not possible.

Can I clone (or copy) a path within an S3 bucket to another path and have it copy all sub-paths and files recursively?

I've seen similar things done with S3FS but I would rather not have to make that step.

I've tried from the shell and it creates the destination directory but nothing inside:

`aws s3api copy-object --copy-source my-bucket/source/ --key dest/ --bucket my-bucket`

Comment: You already have an answer, here, so I'll make this a comment: the command you are using does what it does without throwin an error is because you created that folder in the console.  It's not a container for the things in it -- it's just an empty object with a slash at the end of its name, an aid to navigation in the console.  S3 does not actually *have* folders... the console just shows them to you for convenience.  That's why there is no direct operation for copying a hierarchy -- the hierarchy is an illusion.

Comment: The old console user guide explains this concept more thoroughly than the new one does: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than using the `copy-object` API call, use the nicer [`aws s3 cp`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) command provided by the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/source s3://mybucket/dest --recursive
```

Comment: I would have used `sync` if the buckets were local and cross-region replication if the target bucket is in another region.

Comment: Thanks. Is this also possible with the PHP API? I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: No. The Amazon S3 APIs (for all languages) can only copy one object at a time. The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is actually a Python program that calls the API on your behalf. The `aws s3 cp` and `aws s3 sync` commands have additional programming logic that automatically obtains a list of files, then recursively copies the files. You could write similar logic in PHP, but it is not provided for you.